# How to solve this conditional pdf?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a joint distribution$$f_{XY}(x,y) = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1}\text {exp}\left(-{{x^2+y^2}\over{2\sigma^2}}\right)$$

I need to calculate $$f_{xy}(x,y|x^2+y^2<b^2)$$

I think I should use bayes theorem transfer it and calculate $$f_{xy}(x^2+y^2<b^2|x,y) \ \ \ \ *$$

what confuses me is if function * equates to $$f_{xy}(x^2+y^2<b^2)$$

If it's valid, then 
$$f_{xy}(x,y|x^2+y^2<b^2)={{f_{xy}(x^2+y^2<b^2|x,y) \cdot f_{xy}(x,y)}\over{f_{xy}(x^2+y^2<b^2)}} = \\ =f_{xy}(x,y)$$

So I think it should be wrong. Then how to explain the condition of function * please?

Thank you very much.

---

I have solution:

I wonder if $$F_{xy}(x,y|x^2+y^2<b^2) = F_{x}(-\sqrt{b^2-y^2}<x<\sqrt{b^2-y^2} ) + F_{y}(-\sqrt{b^2-x^2} <y<\sqrt{b^2-y^2}) = \\F_{x}(\sqrt{b^2-y^2})-F_{x}(-\sqrt{b^2-y^2})+F_{y}(\sqrt{b^2-x^2})-F_{y}(-\sqrt{b^2-x^2})$$
is correct?

it is easy to calculate $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$, then I can know $F_{x}$ and $F_{y}$, then it is easy to calculate $F_{xy}(x,y|x^2+y^2<b^2)$ like above. Finally what I need to do is differentiate it.

But I don't know if it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are restricting the uncorrelated bivariate normal distribution to the
disk of radius $b$ about the origin. The 'shape' of the distribution
stays the same, but you need to divide the joint density function by $P(X^2 + Y^2 < b^2),$ which
is less than 1, to 'boost' the new joint density function so it will contain volume $1.$

In the plot below, 100,000 simulated $(X,Y)$-pairs follow the unconditional
bivariate normal distribution with $\sigma = 1.$ The conditional distribution
on the disk of radius $b = 1.5$ includes the black points, but not the red ones. 
Because $X^2 + Y^2 \sim Chisq(df=2),$ we have $P(X^2 + Y^2 < 1.5^2) = 0.6753.$

```
x = rnorm(10^5); y = rnorm(10^5)
cond = (x^2 + y^2 < 1.5^2)
plot(x, y, pch=".", col="red")
points(x[cond], y[cond], pch=".")
mean(cond)        # simulated aprx probability above disk
## 0.67408
pchisq(1.5^2, 2)
## 0.6753475      # exact probability above disk
```

[image]

Comment: @BruceRT I really appreciate your explanation. Your answer make me understand more about conditional probability. But how to calculate the joint probability then, I mean $f_{xy}((x,y), x^2+y^2<b^2)$ ? Because I need to divide this by $P(x^2+y^2<b^2)$, right?

Comment: Gotcha. I will learn about chi-squared distribution things. Thank you very much.

Comment: Right, and you obtain that probability from the chi-squared distribution with df = 2. You may get something more elegant by converting to polar coordinates. Suggest you don't Accept my Answer immediately (up-vote OK); maybe wait to see what others have to say.

Comment: Yeah, you just reminded me to use polar coordinate things to solve disk problems.